# Bootstrap carousel is point to specific address on clicking Next And Previous

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap carousel and facing an unexpected results. Actually when I click on  next or previous next image is not showing And Strange things is that my URL is also change to http:MySITE/Carousel3.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="Carousel3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active"><img src="Carousel1-Side.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="Carousel2-Front.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="Carousel3-Up.jpg" /></div>


    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel3" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon  glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"> </span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>


    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel3" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon  glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share your code which have problem

Comment: The code pasted here is incomplete. I would suggest you to take a look at some KBs for better understanding on carousel first. Try https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp for a kick start.

Comment: used wrong id in <a> tag ..change "Carousel2" to "Carousel3"<a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel3" data-slide="prev">

Comment: @Girija Thanks but its was typeo mistake

Comment: @VinodBalakrishnan FOLLOW same EXAMPLE

Comment: Do you have a jquery reference in your code ? Try adding https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js or higher